# Lambda function cannot be created and deleted

Tags: aws-lambda

I signed in as a root user. Now I'm creating or deleting lambda function. Then the console shows "UnknownError".

I confirmed the browser request. The result is below.

```
{Message: null}
Message: null

Request URL:https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/my-func-name
Request Method: DELETE
Status Code:403 Forbidden
```

I am root user but I got status 403. I think this is suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

this could be happening because of several issues.

**Check your IAM Permissions**

As a fact you should have the permission to everything as root user, there could be an deny statement in the IAM policy preventing of your action. You need to ensure the IAM policy attached to your use, group or role is denying the lambda function you creating.-

**Check the Resource Based Policy**

You have to make sure there are no explicit deny statements in the Resource base policy of the lambda function

**Check the Service Control Policies (SCPs)**

If your AWS account is part of an Organization, check whether if there are any SCPs at the organizational level that might be restricting Lambda function deletion.

If all of the above seems okay, there can be a aws temporary issue happening. Contact AWS support for resolving that.